# use ffmpeg in vb.net service application

Tags: vb.net, ffmpeg

hi  i want to write a  vb.net application using ffmpeg . is there any possible way to run ffmpeg without putting ffmpeg.exe inside the application path or without any hardcoded path ?

Can Any hardcoded path of ffmpeg be used in windows service application ?

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/k c:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe -i rtsp://198.168.1.40/cam  -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -s  -vcodec libx264 -g 60 -vb 500000 -strict experimental   %03d.ts")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't include it with your application, wouldn't you necessarily *have* to provide a hard-coded path?  I suppose you could add the path as an `appSetting` in your config file.

I include it as a resource in my assembly and reference it via the path from the application directory:

```
_ffmpeg = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Resources\ffmpeg.exe"
```

It's similarly kicked off using `Process.Start` as you've noted, but by calling ffmpeg directly, rather than cmd.

```
Dim _FFmpegProcessPropertys As New ProcessStartInfo 
_FFmpegProcessPropertys.FileName = _ffmpeg
_FFmpegProcessPropertys.Arguments = Params
_FFmpegProcessPropertys.UseShellExecute = False
_FFmpegProcessPropertys.RedirectStandardOutput = True
_FFmpegProcessPropertys.RedirectStandardError = True
_FFmpegProcessPropertys.CreateNoWindow = True
Dim FFmpegProcess = Process.Start(_FFmpegProcessPropertys)
```

[image]

Comment: it is service application ,  and if i put the ffmpeg then is this the path to find    "My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath" or   Path.GetDirectoryName([Assembly].GetEntryAssembly().Location) + "/ffmpeg.exe"    which is more approprieate

Answer (score 3):

You can compile the FFmpeg libraries for Windows Runtime and link them.

There's a guide here:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/WinRT

Microsoft also [released](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/06/05/using-ffmpeg-in-windows-applications/) a [FFmpegInterop library](https://github.com/Microsoft/FFmpegInterop). This is useful for playback as it implements a `MediaStreamSource`.